# Geometric progression problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

Please help me solve this:
A man decided to save 50 cents on the first day and on each successive day double the amount saved the previous day.
how long does it take for his total savings to be 1 USD million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simpler than it might seem. Each day, he more than doubles his total money. On the second day, he has 1.5 dollars = 2 dollars - 0.5 dollars. On the third day, he has 3.5 dollars = 4 dollars - 0.5 dollars.

On the $k$th day, he has a total of $2^{k-1}$ dollars - 50 cents, so you only need to find the first value of $k$ that makes this more than 1 million dollars. $2^{20} = 1048576$, so he will have 1 million dollars on the 21st day.

Written formally, you have the sequence $a_n = 2^{n-2}$, representing the amount of money saved on the $n$th day. You're looking for the value of $k$ such that
$$\sum_{n=1}^k a_n > 1000000.$$
Since 
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{n=1}^k 2^{n-2} &=& \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^k 2^{n-1} \\
&=& \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} 2^n \\
&=& \frac{1}{2} (2^k - 1) \end{eqnarray*}$$
and solving $1000000 = \frac{1}{2}(2^k - 1)$ using logs gives $k = 20.93...$, we need $k = 21$ days to save up a million dollars.